# Issue scaling different sized images in CircleImageView

Tags: android, image, android-layout

I'm using [this](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView) repo for circular images and it works quite well. The problem I'm having is when I want to use images of different sizes, say a really big square and a small rectangle. The library uses `scaleType = "CenterCrop`" which works well for the bigger image, it gets a bit zoomed in when cropped, but that's okay since it is a big image and still fills the entire imageView.

The problem is that small images get "**too cropped**" and **too zoomed in** in order to match the edges of the imageView (as is the definition of CenterCrop). Is there a way to still use CenterCrop, but make sure the smaller images don't get bigger than their original size (like when using: `scaletype="fitcenter"`) but also make the bigger images crop correctly?

Simply, I need to use something like CenterCrop, but not as "**zoomed in**", as the images are smaller than the imageView should be displayed like with fitCenter and not horribly zoomed in as they are right now.

I used [this](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide) guide in order to try to understand this problem, but I can't seem to reach a solution.

How do I solve this? Is it possible with this library or should I try to use some other library? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The lib has issue with this, check the issue tracker, you need the height width / weight